# Tool to retrieve binary jpg data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, binary-data

(Asking on behalf of a friend employed in a local bank)

Since he's no programming experience (neither do I with SQL Server), he's looking for a tool which can show all the jpg images stored in a windows SQL Server database. Google didn't give any satisfactory result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Image Viewer](http://www.sqlimageviewer.com/)